# PHP if not in string

Tags: php, syntax

I'am looking for a syntax that will do the following:

```
if('String' not in $string){

//do this

}
```

I am also looking for away to say

```
if('String' in $string){

//do this

}
```

Can anyone help, I have googled for solutions and they seem very confusing.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Possible duplicat [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always use this:

```
if (stristr($string, "string")) {
    //String exists within $string
}else{
    //String does not exist
}
```

http://www.php.net/stristr

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(strpos($string, 'String') !== false) {
    //string exist
}
else{
    //string not exist
}
```